# Should I define a shell function as function x( ) or just x( )?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I've noticed that there are three ways of defining shell functions, and I've never seen it explained anywhere.

```
# Option 1
function log(){

}

# Option 2
log(){

}

# Option 3, added due to answers
function log{

}
```

Is there a different between these three definitions? Do they behave differently, or is it just the look?

Is there a standard to which should be used? I would expect that the first option would be preferable, as I imagine it removes ambiguity somewhere down the line.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit After Answer**: Whoever voted to close as "opinion-based"; I asked for the difference in behaviour, not just why people think I should use which. There is a major difference in the fact that one is only supported in Bash, which means that everybody should aim to be using the second option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The downside to options 1 and 3 is that they both are so-called ["bashisms"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). If you want cross-shell compatibility (e.g., with `sh` in *BSDs) use option 2 because any POSIX shell must support it.

Comment: The *bashism* is the practice of combining `function` with `()`.

Comment: `function` by itself is also a `bash`ism (or, at least, borrowed from `ksh`); the `()` are merely optional if `function` is used.

Comment: @HenkLangeveld -- care to explain further why option 1 is a bashism but option 3 is not?

Comment: @Jon The plain `function` syntax without `()` was introduced to ksh first. David Korn did not want to overload established interfaces with ambiguous behaviour. He probably struggled enough with `echo`.

Answer (score 12):

```
log()
```

is supported by the Bourne Shell family and any type of derivate (dash,yash)
Is the POSIX std syntax and probably the one you want to use to write something compatible with old systems. Probably is the one you want to use.

```
function log () { ...; }
```

Is supported by bash and zsh but using both `function` *and* the `()` is simply WRONG and should be avoided.

```
function log { ...; }
```

Is the Korn Shell syntax and is supported by bash and zsh for compatibility reasons, but is not POSIX

A quote from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete about "function log ()"

*This is an amalgamation between the Korn and POSIX style function definitions - using both the function keyword and parentheses. It has no useful purpose and no historical basis or reason to exist. It is not specified by POSIX. It is accepted by Bash, mksh, zsh, and perhaps some other Korn shells, where it is treated as identical to the POSIX-style function. It is not accepted by AT&T ksh. It should never be used. See the next table for the function keyword. Bash doesn't have this feature documented as expressly deprecated.*

Comment: `function () {` may be overly verbose, but I wouldn't call it wrong: `bash` allows it.

Comment: @chepner `ksh` doesn't allow it on the other hand, so it may be unwise to use.

Comment: I was just drawing a semantic distinction; I wouldn't use the keyword at all, either, and stick with the POSIX syntax (`<name> ()`).

Comment: `but using both function and the () is simply WRONG` Sources? else it's just your opinion

Answer (score 8):

### A bit of history

For absolute Bourne shell and POSIX compatibility, use `log () { ...; }`.  This is especially important in older unix systems and small linux distros that tend to include minimal shell implementations.

There was a special reason for David Korn to introduce the `function` keyword.  He wanted to add
features to functions in `ksh` (ksh93) and wanted to make a clear distinction between normal functions and *enhanced* functions.

In `ksh93`, functions defined with `function name { ...; }` can use local variables, if they're 
declared with `typeset var=value`.

Bash uses the keywords `declare` and `local`, and afaik they work in both types of functions.  Even `typeset` is a synonym for `declare`.

The mixed-up syntax, both `function` *and* `()`, is not compatible with either Bourne, ksh, or POSIX.

---

In my own ksh code, I tend to use lots of functions, and local variables tend to improve the code.
If I expect the code to be reused in a more generic shell than `ksh93` I will revert to POSIX style functions and use subshells to force variables to be local.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Bash Hackers Wiki, the `function` keyword is useless and should never be used, because it's not portable. Apparently, only bash and other ksh-derived shells allow both, and the `function` keyword is a now-obsolete throwback to ksh-style functions. The following references give a better explanation:

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html

Answer (score 1):

That is just your personal call since both syntaxes work fine. But this one:

```
log() {
    echo "logs"
}
```

is the original Bourne and MODERN POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference: **Portability**. The `function` keyword is not POSIX, and only supported by `bash` and `ksh`.